# i want to filter data from 3 drop down using ajax php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

`i want to filter the data according selection of option from three drop down.`

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var institute = $("#institute_wise").val();
var library_type = $("#library_type_wise").val();
var state = $("#state_wise").val();
if(institute=='Select' && library_type=='Select' && state=='Select')
{
        $("#load-a").load("get-filter-values.php?url=all");
        //$('#load-a').html("");
}
```

using any method . can anyone solve this problem.

Comment: what issue you are facing ?

Comment: can youy tell me any mysql query that filter data according to three selected drop down value

Comment: whats your current query ? what output you are getting currently and what is your desired output ? can you show sample data ?